# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. React Hooks, promises

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to render some axios call results to the list of restaurant information that I am mapping onto the current component. So the axios call result is the distance between my current location to the restaurants location which I am using google distance matrix API.
So one of the parameter(my current location) is going to be constant, and the I want to generate the distance between my current location to each of the restaurants that I am going to list on this component. So I mapped the props onto the current component like this:

```
`return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {props.restaurants.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                <p>
                  {item.description}
                  <br />
                  {item.address}
                  <br />
                  {item.phone}
                  <br />
                  {distance}
                </p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );`
```

For the distance, I need to made an axios call to my express server and my express server call google api by using the restaurant location in `props.restaurants`...
the axios call and the function that call to google api and express server are working properly (tested with postman)
I am trying to use React Hooks like below:

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const RestaurantsList = (props) => {
  const [restPlaceId, setCurPlaceID] = useState();
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`/distance/?org=${props.currentPlaceId}&des=${curPlaceId}`)
      .then((result) => {
        setDistance(result);
      });
  }, [restPlaceId]);

  if (props.restaurants.length === 0) {
    return <span>please wait for related product to load</span>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {props.restaurants.map((item, index) => {
            setCurPlaceID(item.place_id);

            return (
              <div>
                <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                <p>
                  {item.description}
                  <br />
                  {item.address}
                  <br />
                  {item.phone}
                  <br />
                  {distance}
                </p>
              </div>
            );

            
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default RestaurantsList;`
```

so I'm trying to update the restPlaceId each time in the .map loop, and then get the new distance by using usEffect. However I am getting this error message: `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`
Can anyone please help me with that error message
or if there's any better idea to render the distance to each of the restaurants?

Answer (score 1):

the error here is that you are updating the state while it renders,
  `setCurPlaceID(item.place_id);`

you should be calling this inside your effect :D

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am new to react hooks. So I should add another useEffect like this: useEffect(()=> {for(let item of props.restaurants){ setCurPlaceID(item.place_id)}} ?

Comment: also, if I updating the CurPlaceId out side of the render method, how do I know which distance is rendered to the correct restaurant location?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `setCurPlaceID(item.place_id)` inside of the render, which is then executing your useEffect, which has `restPlaceId` in it's depedencies.

Every time `props.restaurants.map()` loops, `setCurPlaceID(item.place_id)` is executed, which then executes your useEffect, and the loop goes on and on.

Call `setCurPlaceID(item.place_id);` in a useEffect instead of in the render

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am new to react hooks. So I should add another useEffect like this: useEffect(()=> {for(let item of props.restaurants){ setCurPlaceID(item.place_id)}} ?

Comment: I'd group all of the 'getDistance' calls together in one call, so that you're not calling the API after each resturantListItem renders

Comment: Your expressJS service could accept an array of place_id's, and return the distance for each place, so that you're not making that API call after each list item renders. Then, give each restaurant its 'distance' node, that way when you're rendering the list, you can access distance via 'props.item.distance', instead of calling the API after each 'list item' renders in useEffect